# Small footprint chat app

Tags: memory, chat

When I run Digsby it takes up 140MB of memory.  When I run MS-Messenger it takes 50MB of memory. Is there a multipurpose chat app which takes < 10MB Memory.  This is a big pet peeve of mine.

Comment: 140mb?! Firefox is only taking up 200!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Miranda IM](http://www.miranda-im.org/)** is probably the multi-protocol IM client with the lowest resource usage.

[image]

**[Pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/)** is a bit 'heavier' but still far from WLM or Digsby (and probably more user-friendly than Miranda).

[image]

*Both programs are open-source freeware. portable versions are available. however, they do have their limitations when it comes to video/voice chat support or file transfers.*

I'm using portable versions of both programs; Miranda IM tallies about 8 MB memory usage, Pidgin 38 MB (connecting to 6 different protocols, that is - this includes about 5 MB for the PortableApps launcher).

Comment: +1 for miranda-im. A very minimal setup (it's fully modular, of course) took up <8mb of RAM for me, indeed my current setup takes 4! Connecting to IRC and MSN.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Pidgin with 6 accounts active at once and 30 plugins enabled, and it's currently showing ~28M in the Windows Task Manager "Processes" tab.  That seems pretty reasonable to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try Meebo. As a web page, the size will be depending on your browser.